# Userscript open a client side generated page

Tags: javascript, firefox, userscripts, firefox-addon-webextensions, adblock

I'm writing a userscript which will generate a web page client side and open to view it.

What I want:

- Open a page with specified content generated by the userscript
- It should work on recently Firefox with Violentmonkey

What I'm trying:

convert generated page to `data:` or `blob:` url and then open it by `window.open` / `GM_openInTab`.

What is wrong:

- `window.open(myUrl)`:

  - Adblock Plus with EasyList dislike this. It will close pages with `data:` or `blob:` url automatically.
- `GM_openInTab(myUrl)` aka `chrome.tabs.create({ url: myUrl })`:

  - Firefox disallow it at all. Trying to open a tab with `data:` or `blob:` url will simply do nothing.

Notes: Userscript is a page script (injected script) from extension. Userscript host (like Violentmonkey) will post message to backend script and call web extension api with backend script.

I don't want use a server for this issue, since I don't want anyone collect user info from the network request.

So, What should I do now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen maybe you misread my question.